# Golang iris framework render inside a range

Tags: go, range, render

I'm trying to loop over items and render it in separate template, but `{{ . }}` in `item.html` contains root variables instead of a single item. I tried to assign item to a variable `{{ range $i, $item := .Items }}`, but the result is the same.

```
<!-- list.html -->
{{ range .Items }}
    {{ . }} this one is OK
    {{ render "item.html" }}
{{ end }}

<!-- item.html -->
{{ . }} this one is not
```

Comment: don't use iris http://www.florinpatan.ro/2016/10/why-you-should-not-use-iris-for-your-go.html

Comment: You're not going to find much help for iris in the Go community, when the author of the project refuses to be a responsible member of that community.